# Нужны ли здесь вопросительные знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Может у них есть()
2. — И при чём тут это?
   — Может при том, что это правда()

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных примерах знак вопроса **может ставиться или не ставиться**.

**Пояснение**

Вводное слово **не имеет прямого отношения** к утвердительному или вопросительному характеру предложения, у нас или предположительное утверждение, или вопрос-предположение. А это зависит **от конкретной речевой ситуации.**

Об этом нам говорят примеры из словаря:

**<Может,** в зн. вводн. словосоч. Разг. =Может быть. * Может, поздно, Может, слишком рано (Есенин). **Может быть; быть может,** в зн. вводн. словосоч. Возможно, вероятно. Может быть, кто-л. скоро придёт. Быть может, он сейчас ищет письмо. Вы, может быть, хотите отдохнуть? Вы, может быть, хотите чаю?

Персонаж может кому-то задавать вопрос, в том числе себе, или может просто размышлять, не спрашивая.

2. Примечание. **Вот уж не могу согласиться** с тем, что в данном случае  « можно смело лепить знак вопроса, и если нет непреодолимого желания его не ставить – не ошибешься».

**Сергей Есенин** (как его не вспомнить)

М**ожет, поздно, может, слишком рано,**

И о чем не думал много лет,

Походить я стал на Дон Жуана,

Как заправский ветреный поэт.

**Что случилось?** Что со мною сталось?

Каждый день я у других колен…

Я всегда хотел, чтоб сердце меньше

Вилось в чувствах нежных и простых,

**Что ж ищу** в очах я этих женщин —

Легкодумных, лживых и пустых?

Comment: То есть, если я розмышляю, то знак вопроса не нужен, а если задаю вопрос, то естественно нужен?

Comment: Я согласен, что выбор вопрос/утверждение зависит от конкретной речевой ситуации. Но в том то и фишка, что речевые ситуации становятся похожими друг на друга. Сравните: "Может поздно, может рано походить я стал на дон жуана." и "Может поздно, может рано походить я стал на дон жуана?". Речевые ситуации очень похожи и могут заменять одна другую. Ведь можно же утверждением задать вопрос. Обычное дело.

Comment: Ольга, когда человек размышляет, то все зависит от его психологической задачи. Он может высказать просто предположение, а может задать себе вопрос, на который у него нет еще ответа.  Это мы видим, например,  в стихах Есенина. В диалоге ситуация более определенная. Если вы используете вопрос, то он  обычно обращен к вашему собеседнику, то есть вы ждете от него ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Интересный вопрос, я бы сказал - вопрос вопросов!

Возьмем произвольное предложение. Например: **у них есть**. В вопросительном контексте будет правильно - **у них есть?**, в утвердительном - **у них есть.** Эти два контекста значительно отличаются друг от друга. Если же добавить вводное слово **может**, то утвердительный контекст может быть интерпретирован почти всегда как вопросительный.

Например:

```
Может быть, это иней слетает с них и осторожно потрескивает и позванивает. (Паустовский).
```

Может быть интерпретировано без особого изменения смысла как

```
Может быть, это иней слетает с них и осторожно потрескивает и позванивает?
```

Таким образом:
**Может ... что-то там...** даже в утвердительной форме - констатации всё равно благодаря контексту в большинстве случаев воспринимается как вопрос или вопросительный аргумент. Так что можно смело лепить знак вопроса, и если нет непреодолимого желания его не ставить - не ошибешься.

PS Благодаря такому свойству, слово **может** может когда-нибудь стать вопросительной частицей...